# simple series progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find an expression that summarizes the following series:

```
...0.01  0.05  0.1  0.5  1  5 10 50 100 500...
```

I know this is a very simple question, but for some reason I can't think of any simple formula  that summarizes the series above.

I was thinking about `10^n`, with `-2 < n < 2`, but this doesn't give the 0.05, 0.5, etc. in between.

Care to give me some tips please?

Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an if.  The ratio alternates between 2 and 5. You can also play at trick like this:  $7/2 + 3/2*(-1)^n$. Make sure you get the phase right.